# Repa's slices and shapes

Tags: haskell, repa

I'm having some trouble grasping repa's [`Slice`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.3.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa-Slice.html) module, and specifically how its types and families are used with the [`slice`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.3.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html#v:slice) function. I believe an answer to the following would clear things up for me.

Suppose `x` has shape `shapeOfList [m_0, m_1, …, m_{d-1}]`. Given integers `i < d` and `j < mi`, how do I build something with a suitable type to be *`slice`'s second argument*, that extracts a slice from `x` with shape `shapeOfList [m_0, …, m_{i-1}, m_{i+1}, …, m_{d-1}]` defined by freezing index number `i` at `j`?

Examples in the case `d=2` would be:

- `i=0`: extract row `j`
- `i=1`: extract column `j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let arr =  fromListUnboxed (ix2 3 3) [0..8] :: Array U DIM2 Double
```

`shapeOfList` transform a list to an index,  for instance

shapeOfList [2,2] == (ix2 2 2) -- (Z:. 2 :.2)

```
xs ! shapeOfList [2,2] == 8.0
```

But the function `slice` takes a range of indexes and this range of indexes is represented in REPA using the keywords `Any` and `All`. For instance, to extract the *nth* row from a Matrix the syntax is

```
nRow n =computeUnboxedS $ slice arr (Any :. n :. All) -- xs :: Array U DIM1 Double
 --   nRow 2 = fromList [6.0,7.0,8.0]
```

To extract the *nth* column the Following notation is used

```
nCol n = computeUnboxedS $ slice arr (Any :. n ) -- xs :: Array U DIM1 Double
--  nCol 2 = fromList [2.0,5.0,8.0]
```

It is confusing that in the REPA vocabulary the array index (Z:. i:. i) and the range of indexes (Any :. n :. All) are both called shapes, but one represent only one element index while the other represent an array of indexes.

**EDIT**

to extract the `ith` dimension from an array `traverse` seems the right function, for instance for 3-dimensions

```
-- k = 3 and m = 0
fun3D_i arr = traverse arr (\(Z :. _ :. j :. k ) -> (Z:. j :. k)) (\f (Z :. j :. k )  -> f (Z :. 0 :. j :. k ))`

-- k = 3 and m = 1
fun3D_j arr = traverse arr (\(Z :. i :. _ :. k ) -> (Z:. i :. k)) (\f (Z :. i :. k )  -> f (Z :. i :. 0 :. k )) 

-- k = 3 and m = 2
fun3D_k arr = traverse arr (\(Z :. i :. j :. _ ) -> (Z:. i :. j)) (\f (Z :. i :. j )  -> f (Z :. i :. j :. 0 ))
```

and so on for higher dimensions. 
On the other hand, Template Haskell could help here to select the dimension that you want to extract.

Comment: Oh… I must have completely misunderstood `Any` (and probably `All`), then! What's the type of `Any :. (n :: Int)`?

Comment: Wait, no, I was just confused by your answer. I understand how to get the n'th row or the n'th column from a *matrix*. Slicing to get row `j` is fixing index 0 to be `j`. Getting column `j` is fixing index 1 to be `j`. But, given a `d`-array, how do I fix index `i` (< `d`) to be `j`? The case `d=2` gives matrices, as in your answer, but I get confused for higher `d`.

Comment: Thanks... I have to digest that for a bit!

Comment: I'm sure you are correct, but I'm still not quite getting my head around this. Could you be so kind as to feed me with a teaspoon and show a function `foo :: Int -> Int -> Array r sh1 a -> Array D sh2 a` with the following properties? In `foo i j x`, `x` is a `d`-dimensional array with extents `m_0, …, m_{d-1}`, `i < d` and `0 <= j < m_i`; the return value being a `(d-1)`-dimensional array defined by fixing index `i` in `x` to be `j`. I much appreciate the help :-)

Comment: Actually, I'm not right about the indexes, I'm rewriting things because I messed them completely.

Comment: If you've done your edit, I think we're still misunderstanding eachother. I don't want the n'th column of a 2D-array. I want the n'th m-index of a KD-array (m<K). In the case K=2, m=1 means getting the n'th col, m=0 means getting the n'th row, but I need this (and higher m) for general K.

Comment: I now understand what you want and such function `foo` can't be written in terms of `slice`, because the `Any` and `All` Data types does not allow to constrain the indexes in the way you want to. An alternative can be used `traverse` but you would have to write a function For each k-dimension and for different m.

Comment: Really? That's a shame! But thanks. Put it in your answer and I'll accept it :)